# ssh reverse mysql tunnel with a aliased host

Tags: ssh, mysql, ssh-tunneling

I am trying to ssh into my server and then access the mysql on localhost for quick prototype development when testing on live.

Here is my connection in the server:

```
mysql -h db_master_www -u game -D db_www -p
```

I then setup my tunnel (`sp` is my ssh config name)

```
~ssh -N -L 3336:db_master_www:3306 sp
```

And on my local machine

```
hutber@hutber:~$ mysql -h db_master_www -u game -D db_www -p
ERROR 2005 (HY000): Unknown MySQL server host 'db_master_www' (-2)
```

So logically I'll need to use my host as the ip and not the alias?

Answer (score 0):

Since ssh is providing tunnel from 127.0.0.1:3336 (on the client) to db_master_www:3306 on the remote system, you need to tell the `mysql` command to connect to 127.0.0.1:3336 so the connection'll be forwarded over the tunnel. I'm not particularly familiar with `mysql`, but I think to do this you have to specify `mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3336` (plus other applicable options).

Note: specifying the host as `localhost` rather than `127.0.0.1` *might* work, if the client is a not a Unix/Linux/etc system. If it's a Unix or Unix-like system, [`-h localhost` will make it try to connect via a socket file instead of TCP](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/transport-protocols.html#transport-protocol-selection), and ssh won't forward that.